# How to identify a word with a dollar sign $

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7

I am trying to extract information based on if a string starts with a dollar sign.

I have a string "I bought $BTC"

I am trying to get if word in string starts with dollar sign, get me the word. So I am trying to get in this case "BTC". I tried, string.replace methods and findall, however cannot extract this information. I further read that dollar sign is used as interpolation in Python, I am assuming this is causing the issue.

Are there any ideas that can help me with this?

Comment: Dollar signs are *not* used for interpolation in Python. Simply `'$' in line` does what you are asking, or `word.startswith('$')` if you specifically want to examine the first character of each word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your regex:

```
(?<=\$)\w+
```

It will capture any alphanumeric characters after the $. You can experiment your regex using [pythex.org](https://pythex.org/)

Comment: matches `'a$b'` -- presumably that's not desired?

Answer (score 0):

Following code blocks works for me - returns "BTC". Regex in question is "\$(\w+)"

```
import re

test = "I bought $BTC today"
result = re.search("\$(\w+)", test)
print result.group(1)
```

Group(1) specifies that you're after the characters within the brackets.